How to return the column and row headers for a lookup value?
I am trying to return the column and row headers for the different locations in an array.  In this case the X and Y coordinates of S1 (2,2), S2 (9,3), and S3 (2,9). I have tried using the following formulas:
=XLOOKUP("S1",B2:K11,B1:K1) returns #VALUE!
=MATCH("S2",B2:K11) returns #N/A


You can return the row and column reference, and subtract 1 to account for the title row / column.
For X use;
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$K$11=O2)*(COLUMN($B$2:$K$11)-1))

And Y;
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$K$11=O2)*(ROW($B$2:$K$11)-1))


And without the Column and Row functions,
X;
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$K$11=O2)*($B$1:$K$1))

Y;
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$K$11=O2)*($A$2:$A$11))



You can even use just SUM() instead of SUMPRODUCT(), saves another 7 letters.

To return the row and column Headers, I suggest you use a Table and structured references. Not only does that make inserting/deleting rows/columns of the table simpler, but it also removes the need to compensate (with a manual entry) for the location of the table on the worksheet if it should not start in A1.
Below assumes the variable being looked for is in K2
Row Header: =INDEX(myTable,XMATCH(TRUE,BYROW(myTable,LAMBDA(arr,OR($K2=arr)))),1)

Column Header: =INDEX(myTable[#Headers],, XMATCH(TRUE,BYCOL(myTable,LAMBDA(arr,OR($K2=arr)))))

or, without using LAMBDA or other 365 functions (but note with this method one does have to compensate for the table location; however, it can be determined in the formula automatically, and doesn't have to be manually entered)
Row Header: =INDEX(myTable,MAX(($K2=myTable)*ROW(myTable))-ROW(myTable[#Headers]),1)

Column Header: =INDEX(myTable[#Headers],MAX(($K2=myTable)*COLUMN(myTable))+1-INDEX(COLUMN(myTable),,1))



